# How do I determine if FORCE LOGGING is on for the entire database?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

How can I determine if force logging is on, at the database level. (Not asking about finding out if force logging is on for particular tablespaces.)

What rights are needed to perform the check of the above. (I have SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE, but other than that, pretty limited rights.)

I've tried to find out how to query from the *Reference* and the *Administrator's Guide* manuals.

Version:

```
SQL> select * from v$version;

BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bi
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.4.0  Production
TNS for Solaris: Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT force_logging FROM v$database;
```

The SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE gives you permission to run this statement.